# SQL Select Books base on it's genre stored in a serialize array

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am using laravel. I don't know if there's a query builder for this. I have a books table in my MySQL database with table column of "genre" inside it are serialize array.

Is it possible to use SQL query to select books base on its genre?

[image: a database "books" table]

Like, for example: `SELECT * from books where genre = 'drama';`

Comment: Genre should really be it's own table here. Is it always valid JSON? What version of MySQL?

Comment: There is no direct way. You should really normalize your data. Create a book_to_genre table mapping book_id to genre_id. Otherwise, a hack would be: `SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre LIKE '%s:5:"drama"%'`. You can create the portion in Like dynamically by calculating the number of characters in the genre string which you are trying to match

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Newer versions of MySQL have JSON functions, yes? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: @JacobH This is not JSON format. It is PHP's [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I guess that answers my question of whether it's valid JSON.

Comment: If possible, consider switching to JSON. Then you can use `whereJsonContains()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to store data like this, and normalize your data. Nevertheless , you can use `LIKE` :

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE genre LIKE '%"drama"%'
```

Comment: What if there are two genre with names like `drama` and `melodrama`